# PowerPivot - Average of column for a variable repeating for each row based on time period

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I may be missing something obvious here but as someone who isn't very good I have tried with no success.

Below is my raw data. 3 Variables with differing dates and outputs.

[image]

Below is an image of my output at the moment and what i'd like my output to look like.

***Measure 1 (Column 'I') being the average of all the values in Column 'D' and repeating for each date / output row.***

[image]

Any assistance on how I could create a calculated column / measure to achieve the desired output would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using `ALLSELECTED(...)`.

```
Measure 1:=
 CALCULATE(
  AVERAGE( 'Raw_Data_Table'[Output] ),
  ALLSELECTED('Raw_Data_Table')
 )
```